# How to wrap a text with class?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

After I type my text, I want to wrap `<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum </p>` at VS Code. If I don't need to emmet with a class, I'm using Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation command but it is not work with addition class my p element. It wraps my content with a `<class> Lorem ipsum </class>` instead. So how can I wrap how I want?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write your text : -

1- then press cmd + shift + p or f1 directly
2- type Emmet: Wrap with abbrivation
3- then select your tag, (p, div, etc)

to add class type .dot before class name, [] square brackets to add attributes

an example i tested: `div.textWrapper>p.textContent[style="color: red"]`

Comment: I already do that. But it is not let me add a class or style. It makes my wrap <class> or <style> instead check this: https://i.ibb.co/PZM5k5Y/wlf.png

Comment: You can use .dot to add class, # to add ID,  square brackets to add any attribute like style, name, ..etc